# Compiled Script Using Multiprocessing Crashes When Run

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I wrote a simple script using Multiprocessing to fetch corresponding records from multiple databases, each containing different info for the same record. The script runs fine on my IDE and cmd, but whenever I tried to compile it with PyInstaller I got instant black screen followed by the sound of tons of error messages.

This is based on Python36, involving psycopg2, fiona and shapely as the files generated are shapefiles. But I compiled other scripts involving these modules before and they work fine.

```
import psycopg2
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from shapely.wkt import loads
import re
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Process


def A(list):
    for file in list:
        query database A, generate shapefile for product A


def B(list):
    for file in list:
        query database B, generate shapefile for product B


def C(list):
    for file in list:
        query database C, generate shapefile for product C


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = Process(target=A, args=(scopes,))
    m = Process(target=B, args=(scopes,))
    p = Process(target=C, args=(scopes,))
    e.start()
    m.start()
    p.start()
    e.join()
    print("\nProduct A is done")
    m.join()
    print("Product B is done")
    p.join()
    print("Product C is done")
```

The spec generated during the compiling are like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Scope Process Monitor.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo', 'C:\\Users\\myname\\OneDrive - Company\\Scripts\\Scope Process Monitor'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Scope Process Monitor',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I am guessing I need to limit the use of CPU in the script somewhere, but this is actually my first time trying Multiprocessing module, so I do not know how.